# How to add collapsible form to edit-button inside PHP code? I tried something, but didn't work

Tags: javascript, php

I have been trying for two weeks to add a collapsible button which should reveal the edit-form. I found something, but that **java code didn't work properly inside my PHP code**. For example, it works two by two and it is very annoying.

I tried to add another variables which could change that issue, but didn't work. After that, worked three by three.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
  if($_SESSION['id'] == $row2['id']){

echo "<button type='submit' class='edit-comment'>Edit</button>
  <div class='content'><form class='content edit-form' method='POST' action='".editComments($conn)."'>
  <input type='hidden' name='comment_id' value='".$row['comment_id']."'>
    <input type='hidden' name='user_id' value='".$row['user_id']."'>
    <input type='hidden' name='date' value='".date('d-m-Y H:i:s')."'>
    <textarea class='comment' name='comment'>".$row['comment']."</textarea><br>
    <button id='edit' name='submite' type='submit'>Edit</button>
    </form></div>
    <script>
    var coll = document.getElementsByClassName('edit-comment');
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
      coll[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        this.classList.toggle('active');
        var content = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (content.style.maxHeight){
          content.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
          content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + 'px';
        }
      });
    }
    </script>"; ?>
```

I expect to reveal all the comments, but works just two by two. Here is a picture to understand better what I said:

[image]

Comment: `it works two by two` - could you please try to clarify what this means?

Comment: I clarified with this image: https://i.imgur.com/UztKpY0.png It is not consecutive.

Comment: that doesn't really answer the question - how is one supposed to interpret the image? Do you mean that it does not open all the minimised forms??

Comment: Exactly and I don't understand why, because in HTML works correctly.

Comment: presumably the above code is only a small piece of the full code and this ( the above ) is within a loop? It would be useful perhaps to add the full code / loop

Comment: Here you have the link: https://php.editey.com/file/14dTVTfFh072-I6eIQA2Frobfp8A9-Org I hope that it works

Comment: I'm not prepared to grant permissions to that site... sorry, it's probably perfectly safe and all that but code should be added here

Comment: Where can I upload the codes to see you them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if the following will be of interest as it's likely I have perhaps misunderstood the problem having not been able to view all the code at this point. The following will create ( emulate the creation of ) several of these minimised/hidden forms and a single javascript listener is registed for all of them

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>expanding forms</title>
        <style>
            html *{
                box-sizing:border-box;
                -webkit-transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;
                -moz-transition:    all 350ms ease-in-out;
                -ms-transition:     all 350ms ease-in-out;
                -o-transition:      all 350ms ease-in-out;
                transition:         all 350ms ease-in-out;          
            }
            .content{
                display:none;
                margin:1rem 0;
            }
            .expanded{
                min-height:10rem;
                max-height:10rem;
                height:10rem;
                display:block;
                border:1px solid black;
                padding:0.25rem;
            }
            .minimised{
                height:0rem;
            }
            button.edit-comment{display:block;}
            textarea{
                width:80%;
                height:9.25rem;
                margin:auto;
                resize:none;
            }
            form > button[type='submit']{
                float:right;
                width:10%;
                padding:1rem;
                background:gray;
                color:white;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e=>{
                Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll('button.edit-comment') ).forEach( function( bttn ){
                    bttn.addEventListener( 'click', function(e){
                        let div=this.nextElementSibling;
                            div.classList.toggle( 'expanded' )
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            for( $i=1; $i <=10; $i++ ){
                printf("
                    <button type='submit' class='edit-comment'>Edit</button>
                    <div class='content'>
                        <form class='hidden-content edit-form' method='POST' action='%s'>
                            <input type='hidden' name='comment_id' value='%d'>
                            <input type='hidden' name='user_id' value='%d'>
                            <input type='hidden' name='date' value='%s'>
                            <textarea class='comment' name='comment'>%s</textarea>
                            <button name='sub' type='submit'>Edit</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>",

                    '',
                    $i,
                    $i,
                    date('d-m-Y H:i:s'),
                    'This is a comment #'.$i
                );
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, it works, you're a genius. Also I wonder how you can understood what I meant. :)) Thank you once.

Comment: lucky guess - I'm glad that I managed to help you though, good luck with the rest of your project

Comment: Thank you, I will finish maybe in one month and even I want to show you before make it public. Have a nice day!